# how to give valid default value to a primary auto increment integer in mysql?

Tags: mysql, increment, auto

I'm working with MySQL 6.3 and JDBC.
I don't know what can be a valid value for the auto-increment primary key in the query below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (customerID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '1', customerName VARCHAR(20), customerLastName VARCHAR(40)", customerPhoneNumber VARCHAR(11), customerCharge INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (customerID));
```

Instead of '1' for default value, I tried '0', 1, 0 and even null.Even in a lot of sources that I searched they used null default value with

> NOT NULL

in query but mine gives an exception.

using UNIQUE instead of PRIMARY KEY works fine for me but I'm asking if there is a solution to keep the primary key, auto increment, and a default value together.

Comment: There is no mysql 6.3.  It went from 5.x to 8.x. Please state the version of mysql, not the workbench version.

Comment: I think I understand the problem.  You don't insert anything into that field.  If you have a table id - autoincrement, stuff- varchar(20), your insert should ONLY reference "stuff", not id.

Comment: @TGray Or, you can specify NULL  as the value for an auto_increment column to get the auto increment value.

Comment: yeah that's right.now i tested this in my query.filled the value of id with null and auto increment just worked fine.i don't know why all it would not work before i posted here :)

Comment: i think it was all because my query from jdbc can not work. a query that contains IF NOT EXISTS doesn't work from jdbc.i think the problem solved when i droped the table from workbench and then again i ran the project from ide

Comment: @GarrGodfrey You're right.  It's really not a good standard to adopt, but I agree, you can specify NULL in the values or select clause for the insert.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

A default value doesn't really make sense with AUTO_INCREMENT. AUTO_INCREMENT basically means the default is +1 (or +x) of the highest value (which can be set on a table).

In other words, don't ever use AUTO_INCREMENT and DEFAULT at the same time.

*EDIT*
I don't know what version of mysql you are really using, but on 5.7 this works as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CUSTOMER (customerID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, customerName VARCHAR(20), customerLastName VARCHAR(40), customerPhoneNumber VARCHAR(11), customerCharge INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (customerID));
```

Comment: thanks but it will give an exception telling the auto_increment  doesn't have default value, so that's why i'm trying to use them both
tnx again

Comment: what is the exact error message? Works fine in 5.7 but maybe it's a server config issue.

Comment: there is no default for auto-increment fields.  you can only set the start value and increment value.

Comment: yes yes you were right my friend.now that i checked it works fine

Comment: yes, and auto_increment_increment is a server setting, not a table or schema setting, and you can only set start value after creating the table.